# Swift Sound on repeat

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this function, that I bring to life in first scene:

```
    func ThemeSound() {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("InfinityThemeMain", ofType: "wav") {
            let enemy1sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
            println(enemy1sound)

            var error:NSError?
            ThemePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: enemy1sound, error: &error)
            ThemePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            ThemePlayer.play()
        }
    }
```

but the problem is, It plays the theme just once. I need it to be played on repeat. And I thought I knew how to make this happen.

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(ThemePlayer), SKAction.waitForDuration(2.55)]))
```

But I can't paste in the ViewController, because runAction needs a child to attach it to.
Any other way I could do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just set the numberOfLoops property to a negative number.

```
ThemePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
```

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html):

> numberOfLoops
>   The number of times a sound will return to the beginning, upon reaching the end, to repeat playback.
>
> ...
>
> var numberOfLoops: Int
>
> ...
>
> A value of 0, which is the default, means to play the sound once. Set a positive integer value to specify the number of times to return to the start and play again. For example, specifying a value of 1 results in a total of two plays of the sound. **Set any negative integer value to loop the sound indefinitely until you call the stop method**.

You may also need to [make your AVAudioPlayer a property, rather than a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485536/avaudioplayer-must-you-create-a-property-for-it-to-work-xcode). As it stands, with automatic reference counting, I think your local ThemePlayer instance is likely to be deallocated by ARC. Someone who knows AVAudioPlayer better than me might be able to comment on that.

(As an aside, you might want to follow Apple's convention of naming object instances by starting with lowercase letters, e.g. `themePlayer` rather than `ThemePlayer`. It'll make your code easier for other people to read.)

Comment: Make sure to use the m4a format, as this avoids having an audible gap between the repetitions. Converting is supported natively on OSX, as described here: http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/30/convert-audio-to-m4a-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: @nontomatic When I convert it to a m4a, setting the numberOfLoops to -1 doesn't make it repeat.  Please help! I have a school project due tomorrow ;(

Comment: Alex, there must be an issue with your code, it should work. I suggest posting your code, maybe opening a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I make it repeat by using `Timer()`
here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {

       // var player = AVAudioPlayer()


        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "beeb", withExtension: "wav")

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
        } catch {
            print("No sound found by URL")
        }



        alertation(title: "click stop to stop", msg: "")


    }


    func alertation(title:String,msg:String)
    {

        player.play()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.player.play()
        })



        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        var stop = alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "STOP", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

             self.player.stop()
            self.timer.invalidate()

        }))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



}
```